# Required listener configuration for Kubernetes ConfigMap

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I have a configuration file as part of the Kubernetes ConfigMap data section. Whenever there is a change in the content of the configuration file(ConfigMap data:), there should be some trigger/listener resulting in some invocation. (As part of this invocation, I need to have some code implemented which restarts some service objects).

Is there some Kubernetes configuration available that can be used to configure this listener for ConfigMap?.

ConfigMap sample :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-glare-configurations
data:
  glare.conf.template: |
    use_stderr = false
    bind_port = 9494
    default_api_limit = {{ .Values.configruations.default_api_limit | default 150 }}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support in Kubernetes for this feature at the time of writing this answer afaik.

Update:

You can use one of the [supported client libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/) and write a custom listener.

Here is an [example](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/examples/pod_namespace_watch.py) of how to watch for pods using the python client library.

---

The below section is useful to provide rolling updates to the objects like `Deployments` in case of changes in the resources that they reference like `ConfigMap`/`Secret`.

There is a [feature request](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22368) in the works for the requirement.

You can have a look at [`Reloader`](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader) which is a custom plugin used exactly for this requirement.

Comment: Hi @krishna-chaurasia, is the Reloader part of third-party library ?

Comment: yes, it requires to be installed separately and can be done easily using its `helm-chart`.

Comment: Thank you, but using an additional chart for listener purpose is something i need to check still.

Comment: there is a feature in the works but nothing as of now: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/22368

Comment: Hi Krishna, the above link is rolling update of configmap and not related to listener right ?

Comment: yes, updating the Kubernetes objects based on changes in `cm`/`secrets` mounted on it. you'll need to write a custom listener using a kubernetes client library.

Comment: I have updated the answer and added an example of writing a listener using the python client library.